# Can I use multiple inputs to my dash plotly callback, but only have one trigger the callback?

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible to use multiple inputs to my dash plotly callback, but only have one trigger the callback? It doesn't seem so.

I want to trigger the callback only when a button is pressed. I don't know how to get the other data I need within the callback function if I don't pass it as one of the inputs.

This runs if I "get_file" changes, even if "Button" is not clicked

```
@app.callback(
    Output("file_to_upload", "children"),
    [Input("Button", "n_clicks"),
     Input("get_file", "filename"), 
     Input("get_file", "contents")]
)
def get_query_file(n_clicks, uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
```

This doesn't work because I need the filename and content within the function

```
@app.callback(
    Output("file_to_upload", "children"),
    [Input("Button", "n_clicks")]
)
def get_query_file(n_clicks):
```

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Dash.
Try putting your git_files into a State argument instead of Input, like so:

```
@app.callback(
Output("file_to_upload", "children"),
Input("Button", "n_clicks"),
[State("get_file", "filename"), 
State("get_file", "contents")]
)
def get_query_file(n_clicks, uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
```

Comment: Note that States takes information but does not trigger the callback like Input does.